# Resources with sample questions for testing knowledge about Java (collections, swing, etc)

Tags: java, resources

I need sites that provide a lot of sample questions about collections and generics and swing and etc.  I have checked a lot but I couldn't find those sites.
Can you help me?

Comment: Sample questions for learning my lessons like collections and swing better :)

Comment: I think the title needs to be changed

Answer (score 2):

Javaranch has links to SCJP practice tests, which should cover basic java stuff. http://faq.javaranch.com/java/ScjpMockTests

Answer (score 2):

[Java BlackBelt](http://www.javablackbelt.com) has more java test questions than you can shake an iterator at.

Answer (score 0):

Java BlackBelt is now named [http://knowledgeblackbelt.com](http://knowledgeblackbelt.com/ref=froland). There is a great deal of exams, courses (online training with a personal coach) and workshops (training projects) there.